# Get refined set using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to get a set of items from a list.

```
var sampleDataGroups = SampleDataSource.GetGroups("AllGroups");
var final=sampleDataGroups.Select(p => p.Description.Equals("Test1");
```

`sampleDataGroups` gets all the groups in the list. How do I refine the list to get only those groups whose `Description` property value is "Test1"?

I tried to achieve this with the linq query in `var final`, but it isn't working.

I want to get all the Groups where the Description is "Test1".

Comment: Kindly mark the best answer "as answer", thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Where clause will help you achieve this. Also, you forgot a closing bracket at the end.

```
var final = sampleDataGroups.Where(p => p.Description.Equals("Test1"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to filter a query is using the `where` statement, giving it your desired condition so only those items where they match this condition will be returned back.

try this one:

`var sampleDataGroups = SampleDataSource.GetGroups("AllGroups").where(g=>g.Description=="Test1");`

The previous statement means that only items which have their description property equal to `Test1` will be returned back, discarding all the other ones.

the following links are very helpful getting you started with LINQ.

1- Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#):
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397927.aspx

2- an article from MSDN which clarifies the `where` statement usage scenario
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should use statement Where:

```
var final=sampleDataGroups.Where(p => p.Description.Equals("Test1");
```